# How to see whole answers for long floats on TI-83?

Tags: calculator

Disclaimer: I guess answers on calculators are on topic for this SE site, tried searching and found alot of non-closed/moved questions. If not, please say so and i'll be happy to move the post

Especially with complex numbers the small screen of the TI-83 calculator often does not show the whole numbers and just end with dot dot dot as seen on the below picture. Is it possible to, either scroll to see the whole answer? Or make the calculator not show that many digits after the float mark?

[image: enter preformatted text here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you get the ... after an answer you can just press the right arrow to reveal more digits.

You can also set the accuracy under `MODE`. The default is set to `FLOAT`, but you can tell the calculator to round answers to what accuracy you want.

Comment: Thanks, the rounding was just what i was after!